# Inline-Block padding/margin issue

Tags: html, css

What I want to happen: The two white divs should never change width. But the orange space around them should get smaller as the window is sized smaller. When the window becomes too small for the two boxes to sit next to each other, then I want the boxes to pop under each other. Check my image for a better understanding.

At the moment I placed a WrongSpaceDiv between the two white divs to use as a placeholder. This works fine except for the fact that the WrongSpaceDiv's width doesn't get smaller as the window gets smaller.

Padding and margins don't seem to work (unless I'm using it wrong of course) because you need to set them so large, that the boxes pop under each other way too early.

I need a solution that allows me to control the max width of the middle space. The outside spaces can just keep getting larger as the window becomes larger.

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
}

.MainDiv {
  text-align: center;
}

.WrongSpaceDiv {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.TheDivs {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="TheDivs">
  </div>
  <div class="WrongSpaceDiv">
  </div>
  <div class="TheDivs">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `max-width` to the container and use flex inside it to align items:

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
}

.MainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.TheDivs {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainDiv">
  <div class="TheDivs">
  </div>
  <div class="TheDivs">
  </div>
</div>
```